# How do I assign node shape attributes to just one column of edgelist?

Tags: r, igraph

I am plotting in igraph and having difficulty plotting with an attribute for node shape. I have added attribute data from a csv file and have tried to indicate that it only applies to one column of my edgelist using ifelse (I have a separate attribute file for the other column of the edgelist).

The attribute is designated with "TRUE" and "FALSE" - and I would like to have the nodes designated "TRUE" represented with squares (and all other nodes- including the nodes in other other column of the edgelist- as circles). This attribute only applies to column 1 "org" in my edgelist. But when I attempt to plot, I get an error message.

I am expecting a network with some nodes represented with squares. The plot works fine when I don't try to include the code for shape. I have been getting this error message when I plot: Error in igraph.check.shapes(params("vertex", "shape")) : 
  Bad vertex shape(s): NA.

Code:

```
el[,"org"]=as.character(el[,"org"])
el[,"office"]=as.character(el[,"office"])
el=as.matrix(el)
g=graph.edgelist(el[,1:2])



# shape vector:

c=read.csv(file.choose("LA2016_att2"))
V(g)$type=as.character(c$type[match(V(g)$name,c$org)])

V(g)$shape <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "square", "circle")
V(g)$shape <- ifelse(V(g)$type %in% el[,1], yes = V(g)$type, no = "circle")

# Plot:
m <- layout_with_kk(g)
plot(g, layout=m, edge.arrow.size=.2, vertex.label.font=1, vertex.label.cex=.6, vertex.label.color="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please provide a dataset, so we can reproduce the graph and the errors.

You don't have to write the setter of the shape twice ( `V(g)$shape <- ...` ). The error is shown because you set the *shape* attribute to be equal with the *type* in the second ifelse statement. Simply setting the *shape* to square, if the condition evaluates true, and circle otherwise may solve your problem:

```
V(g)$shape <- ifelse(V(g)$type %in% el[,1], "square", "circle")
```